# undefined method `ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0x007fc17c3fc6c8> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, bundler

Just pulled latest code and now getting:

```
...my_app/Gemfile:2:in `evaluate': 
undefined method `ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0x007fc17c3fc6c8> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: What's on line 2 in the Gemfile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ruby` method that allows you to specify the version of Ruby your project should use was [only added in Bundler 1.2](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/whats_new.html). You’ve got a project with a `Gemfile` that uses this new `ruby` method, but have an old version of Bundler. You just need to get Bundler 1.2 with

```
gem install bundler
```

and you should be good to go.